# How can I have geoserver reading long, latitude coordinates from MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, geoserver, mysql-8.0

I am trying to render a map layer in Geoserver 2.19.0. The data is stored in a MySQL 8.0 database using SRID 4326.
The layer was created using the SRID mentioned before.

I place a fragment of some settings from *Edit Layer* page

[image: here]

The following exception is displayed when I go to layer preview, and click on *Open Layers*

```
12 Apr 18:41:28 ERROR [geoserver.ows] -
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Rendering process failed. Layers: AHS-CommonUI:map_outline
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:660)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
        at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:171)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Latitude -272.812500 is out of range in function st_geomfromtext. It must be within [-90.000000, 90.000000].
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureReader.runQuery(JDBCFeatureReader.java:282)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Latitude -272.812500 is out of range in function st_geomfromtext. It must be within [-90.000000, 90.000000].
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:104)
```

As a background, in MySQL 8.0 the coordinates were inverted from longitude-latitude to latitude-longitude as an standard ([here a reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-wkt-functions.html)), you can still storing data using long-lat if you use the option *axis-order=long-lat* when executing the function ST_GEOMFROMTEXT, but seems like Geoserver is not taking this in consideration.

Also, my problems began when I moved from MySQL 5.6 to MySQL 8.0.
With MySQL 5.6 I was storing the geometry data using this function.

```
GEOMFROMTEXT(?, 4326)
```

After moving to MySQL 8.0 I am doing with this function.

```
ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(?, 4326, 'axis-order=long-lat')
```

*Note: I am using the option axis-order=long-lat to avoid having to change my other implementation. The mentioned option is supported since MySQL 8.0*

Already tried using the latest version of Geoserver, until today 2.20-Nightly (Before I was using 2.15.3 which is not compatible with MySQL 8.0)

As a reference, here is a fragment of the definition of the table used to generate the layer:

```
CREATE TABLE `map_outline` (
  `_OID_` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `geometry_wkt` geometry NOT NULL SRID 4326,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_OID_`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Am I missing something? 
Any configuration in Geoserver I need to enable/disable? 
Is this a bug?

Comment: Your error is inside MySQL (com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation) - you don't say how your data is stored but there is a problem with the axis order in the way it is being read. I suspect you don't have a geometry column so creating one would be a good first step.

Comment: @IanTurton I added more context to the comment. 
The table contains a geometry column (added table definition to the post), also this was working with Geoserver 2.15.3 before migrating to MySQL 8.0.

Thanks for your contribution and feedback.

Comment: The problem is that 4326 is ill defined and we try to avoid making assumptions about it preferring to trust the database. It appears that you have confused MySQL by forcing a lon/lat order and it doesn't know how to handle that. It's possible that GeoServer's request can be updated to handle this case but I suspect that it won't be that easy. You'll need to turn on GeoTools level logging and see what query GeoServer is sending and how that can be made to work correctly. Then put all that information in a bug report and submit a PR to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for a GeoServer update, I solved with `ST_SwapXY` in a SQL View:

```sql
SELECT id, ST_SwapXY(geometry) as geom
FROM my_table
```

For create a SQL View layer:

[image]